# Do a specific inequality hold under integration?

Tags: integration, derivatives, inequality, integral-inequality

As we know that if  we have the inequality $f\leq g$, it does not imply $f'\leq g'$.

Now Let  $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for each $x\in [a,b]$,
 where $0<a,b<\infty$.

Is it possible to prove

$$\int_{a}^{b} f'(x)dx\leq \int_{a}^{b}g'(x)dx$$

,where $f$ denotes the derivative of $f$?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Your first claim is not true. Take $f(x) = e^{-x}$ and $g(x) = -e^{-x}.$ Then $f \leq g$ but $f' \geq g'.$

Comment: To use MathJax, use dollar symbols to wrap up you expressions.

Comment: @sobi  and M. Winter ,Sorry. I have edited the question.    xbh Thanks  for giving the suggestion.

Comment: @user586256 Have you heard of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: @sobi, Yes I know, but how can we use that ?

Comment: @user586256 My bad, you can't really use it. I didn't think it through, sorry!

Answer (score 6):

The question you ask has an obvious simpliciation: by the fundamental theorem of calculus, you are asking:

> Is it possible to prove
>   $$ f(b) - f(a) \leq g(b) - g(a) $$

Including the constraints, we can simplify even further

> Suppose $p \leq q$ and $r \leq s$. Can we prove $p-r \leq q-s$?

And the answer is no: you cannot *subtract* like inequalities. The problem is basically that you are flipping the sign, which reverses the inequality: i.e. $-r \geq -s$.

---

There is a theorem regarding integration and inequalities, however:

> If $f \leq g$, $a \leq b$, and the following integrals are defined, then you have
>   $$ \int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \leq \int_a^b g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x  $$

This does not hold with strict inequality unless you make additional assumptions. (e.g. $f,g$ continuous and $a < b$)

Comment: Thanks. Now its clear to me.

Comment: Minor point regarding last sentence. If $a<b$ and $f<g$ then we have $\int_{a} ^{b} f<\int_{a} ^{b} g$. The integrals here are Riemann and $f, g$ are Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 2):

Take $f=0$ adn $g$ to be any non-negative strictly decreasing function. Then $\int_a^{b} g'(x) \, dx=g(b)-g(a) <0=\int_a^{b} f'(x) \, dx$.

Comment: Thanks K.R. Murthy. This is also a nice example to contradict.

Answer (score 1):

Take the functions $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=-1/x$. We have $f(x)>g(x)$ on $(0,\infty)$, but also

$$f'(x)=0< \frac1{x^2} = g'(x).$$

But for $[a,b]\subseteq (0,\infty)$ it holds

$$f'(x)\le g'(x) \quad\implies\quad \int_a^b f'(x)\,\mathrm dx \le \int_a^b g'(x)\,\mathrm dx,$$

so we have a counter-example to your desired inequality. It cannot be proven.

Comment: Thanks. I want to add one more query . Let us take $f(x),g(x)\geq 0, for all x\in[a,b].$  Can we still prove the contradiction?

Comment: @user586256 Yes. Just shift $g$ and $f$ up by some constant, e.g. $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=1-1/x$ and restrict to $[a,b]\subseteq (1,\infty)$. And you can surely find example that work on all of $\Bbb R$, e.g. $f(x)=\pi$ and $g(x)=\arctan(x)+\pi/2$.

Comment: Yes got it, thanks again. But I think inequality holds if  in the inequality  $f\leq g$, our $g=e^x, 0<x<\infty.$  Am I right?

Comment: @user586256 Unfortunately No. Take $f(x)=e^x-1/(x+1)$ which is always smaller, but $$f'(x)=e^x+\frac1{(x+1)^2} > g'(x).$$

Comment: Yes I was wrong, and I think we can not prove  even with some constant $C>0$ such that  $f\leq Cg$, as [at]Hurkyl have explained above the  technical problem with subtraction of inequalities.

Comment: @user586256 If answers have been helpful for you, consider *voting*. Also consider *accepting* (with the green checkmark) the answer you like the most.

Comment: I do not have that much reputation.

Comment: @user586256 I am fairly sure that accepting an answer is possible regardless of the reputation. But do not hurry, take your time. Maybe even better answers are incoming.